# Imperva firewall SVN block

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, firewall

We are accessing SVN server from out client environment. Client is using Imperva SecureSphere Web Application Firewall. Imperva is not allowing us checkout or check In to the SVN from tortoise SVN client.
[Imperva error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcwC3.jpg)

Comment: Seems like a configuration error. You should work with your Client to allow your team's IP(s) access to their systems.

Comment: There is nothing you can do yourself to solve this. Contact your client (e.g. his system administrator) for assistance with this.